# upstream sent more data than specified in "Content-Length" header while reading upstream

Tags: nginx, debian, django

I have django app (based on Mezzanine).

My nginx conf looks like:

```
upstream myhost {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name www.myhost.ru myhost.ru;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    keepalive_timeout    15;

    location / {
        proxy_redirect      off;
        proxy_set_header    Host                    $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Protocol    $scheme;
        proxy_pass          http://myhost;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root            /home/myhost/virtualenvs/myhost/project;
        access_log      off;
        log_not_found   off;
    }

    location /robots.txt {
        root            /home/myhost/virtualenvs/myhost/project/static;
        access_log      off;
        log_not_found   off;
    }

    location /favicon.ico {
        root            /home/myhost/virtualenvs/myhost/project/static/img;
        access_log      off;
        log_not_found   off;
    }

}
```

In browser I see "Internal Server Error".

I see following errors in /var/log/nginx/errir.log:

```
2013/04/20 12:24:57 [warn] 11479#0: *1 upstream sent more data than specified in "Content-Length" header while reading upstream, client: 89.189.170.4, server: www.rureads.ru, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "myhost.ru"
2013/04/20 12:38:14 [warn] 11481#0: *19 upstream sent more data than specified in "Content-Length" header while reading upstream, client: 89.189.170.4, server: www.rureads.ru, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "myhost.ru"
```

What may cause the problem? How to fix this?

Comment: What service/process is listening on port 8000?

Comment: gunicorn on port 8000

Comment: Then it sounds like gunicorn is misbehaving a bit.  There's a note in the documentation here to turn off `proxy_buffering` and use an async gunicorn worker when using certain features which make creative use of the HTTP protocol, are you using any of those?  These log entries are just warnings, and don't indicate that a request failed; is it actually causing a problem in the application?

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this issue? I ran into it this morning as well with a similar setup (including Mezzanine) but I don't see any resolutions anywhere on the web.

Answer (score 0):

modify nginx conf :

```
proxy_buffering off;
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I struggled with this one for quite awhile. In my case, I had an import error relating to mezzanine lurking in my django application (which didn't show itself when using the django development server). For some reason (perhaps a gunicorn bug?), this import error wasn't being displayed in the browser (even with DEBUG=True) or logged by gunicorn. Instead, I was just getting an "Internal server error" from nginx and the "Upstream sent more data that specified..." message in the nginx error log. The gunicorn logs just logged the request as if everything went fine. Given that no specific error was being logged anywhere, it took me a long while to find the import error and fix it. In my case, I was able to get the django error page to show up only by commenting out all MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in settings and setting DEBUG=True. This revealed the import error, which I fixed. Then, I re-enabled the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, restarted the gunicorn workers and everything worked fine!

Hopefully this saves someone some time.